# Null pointer Exception when calling asynch task from context

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask

My asynch task working well when calling asynch task from context but,
when setting the values to textview getting null pointer exception

Am not getting reference to textview...Please help me how to get reference when calling asynch task from context class...

```
05-14 11:44:45.279: E/AndroidRuntime(18314): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-14 11:44:45.279: E/AndroidRuntime(18314): Process: com.example.asynctest, PID: 18314
05-14 11:44:45.279: E/AndroidRuntime(18314): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-14 11:44:45.279: E/AndroidRuntime(18314):    at com.example.asynctest.MainActivity$MyAsync.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:50)
05-14 11:44:45.279: E/AndroidRuntime(18314):    at com.example.asynctest.MainActivity$MyAsync.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
05-14 11:44:45.279: E/AndroidRuntime(18314):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
05-14 11:44:45.279: E/AndroidRuntime(18314):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
05-14 11:44:45.279: E/AndroidRuntime(18314):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
05-14 11:44:45.279: E/AndroidRuntime(18314):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-14 11:44:45.279: E/AndroidRuntime(18314):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-14 11:44:45.279: E/AndroidRuntime(18314):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
05-14 11:44:45.279: E/AndroidRuntime(18314):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-14 11:44:45.279: E/AndroidRuntime(18314):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-14 11:44:45.279: E/AndroidRuntime(18314):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
05-14 11:44:45.279: E/AndroidRuntime(18314):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
05-14 11:44:45.279: E/AndroidRuntime(18314):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

MainClass.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView textView;
    String textctx;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView.setText("Main class Text");
        MyContextClass contextClass=new MyContextClass(this);
        contextClass.MyContextMethod();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void callfromcontext(String contexttext) {               

        new MyAsync().execute(contexttext);

    }

    class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String sometext=params[0]; 
            return sometext;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            System.out.println("result"+result);            
            textView.setText(result);

        }


    }

}
```

MyContextClass.java

```
public class MyContextClass {

    Context context;
    public MyContextClass(Context ctx) 
    {
        this.context=ctx;           
        MainActivity activity=new MainActivity();
        String contexttext="Context Class Text";
        activity.callfromcontext(contexttext);
    }

    public void MyContextMethod()
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: Please post the complete `NovvTrend` class.

Comment: hi i posted my sample code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MainActivity activity=new MainActivity();
```

Never instantiate activities with `new`. They won't be good for anything you'd want an activity for.

Specifically in your case: the lifecycle method `onCreate()` won't get run for that activity object and the `TextView` reference there is `null`.

If you really need to launch an activity, use an `Intent`.

If you just need to get a reference to your activity, pass it around as an argument, e.g.

```
void methodThatNeedsActivity(MainActivity activity) {
  activity.someMethod();
}

// call from MainActivity
otherObject.methodThatNeedsActivity(this);
```

Comment: getting unable to initiate activity componentinfo error

Comment: ... doing what? Also that's just the top-level problem, the root cause is in the nested exceptions in the stacktrace.

Comment: Thanks its working :)  i forgot to create an empty constructor...Thanks for yours Help!!!